EF Core ValueConverter string to bool for nullable string column
I'm looking for some feedback to help understand if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible. I have a database column that is a nullable string type (mostly varchar) and I am using a ValueConverter to convert the string db value into an entity bool value based on if the db value is null, 'N' (false) or 'Y' (true).
I also wanted to eliminate the nullable bool? type on the entity property using the EntityConfiguration. The problem I'm now having is that when I make the entity property a non-null bool instead of bool? the migration fails saying that the type must be nullable.
First I have this ValueConverter to convert my string values into a non-nullable bool.
internal class NullableStringToBoolValueConverter : ValueConverter<bool, string?>
{
    public NullableStringToBoolValueConverter() : base(ToDbValue, ToEntityValue) { }

    private static HashSet<string> YesTypes = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "1", "Y", "Yes" };
    private static HashSet<string> NoTypes = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "0", "N", "No" };

    private static Expression<Func<string?, bool>> ToEntityValue
        => value => value != null && YesTypes.Contains(value) ? true : false;

    private static Expression<Func<bool, string?>> ToDbValue
        => value => value == false ? "N" : "Y";

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow nulls to pass into converter for conversion.
    /// </summary>
    public override bool ConvertsNulls => true;
}

I then have the entity using a non-nullable bool property.
public class EntityName
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

Lastly, I have the following configuration for this property.
public class EntityNameConfiguration : ...omitted
{
    builder.Property(e => e.IsActive)
        .HasConversion<StringToBoolValueConverter>()
        .HasMaxLength(10)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .IsRequired(false)
}

I expected EF to know that the nullable string will be converted by the ValueConverter to a non-nullable bool but I'm instead getting an error that says I have to make the IsActive property nullable.
Is what I want to do here possible?
UPDATE: Something I failed to mention is that the posted code here will fail to run. EF throws a runtime error when IsRequired(false) is used with a non-nullable entity property.
I've now created a local db that is created using the non-nullable property which of course creates a non-nullable column. I then change the column to be nullable, just to test, and leave the EF stuff as non-nullable. This gives me a new error which looks like EF internally is expecting a non-nullable db column and finds a null column instead.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method165(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I'm starting to think that using a non-null entity property with a nullable column isn't possible. I thought (hoped) that the ValueConverter would allow this to work.

When a ValueConverter receives a null value it is simply not called, so your converter won't work for null.

Why do you even want a null value in the DB? Just set N as the default value, since you actually only wants two values.

Haha, I don't want a null value in the db, but this is not my doing. I've been put in the position of having to work with a db someone else created. At least the value converter once implemented will read the null as a false and whent the record is saved again it will overwrite the null with either N or Y

you can try, editing the Migration that is created when the type is changed to make the column nullable,
i am not sure if ef will update the previous rows if you make the default value to be false, you can do it with raw sql in the migration.
if this fails you would need to do the update first and then apply the migration.
